# Get new lines of syslog to my custom program(daemon)

Tags: c, go, daemon, syslog

I need to get new lines of syslog to my c(or golang) program when it written.

The program run as linux daemon, and it will be always on memory.

Here, the picture explains full code flow that I needed.

Run Flows

[image: 1]

Please check and guide me how.
regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nxadm/tail](https://github.com/nxadm/tail) which mimics UNIX `tail`. If you need to have a finer grain of control, you can use `inotify` feature with [fsnotify](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify).

### Tail:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nxadm/tail"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := tail.TailFile("/var/log", tail.Config{Follow: true})

    for line := range t.Lines {
        fmt.Println(line.Text)
    }

}
```

### fsnotify:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
)

func main() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                log.Println("event:", event)

            case err, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    // Add a path.
    err = watcher.Add("/var/log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Block main goroutine forever.
    <-make(chan struct{})
}
```